# How do I find the number of files in a directory?

Tags: android, file, directory, numbers, adb

I am trying to simply count the number of files in a directory on an Android device. I am using adb shell via a Windows10 command prompt. Utilities like find, wc, tree and tail do not seem to work e.g:

```
`tree . | tail -1`
```

gives

```
`tmp-mksh: tree: not found`
`tmp-mksh: tail: not found`
```

I could write some java to do it but that would just be silly :) Any ideas?

Comment: You can install `busybox` and try out these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$ adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ cd yourDirectory
generic_x86:/yourDirectory $ ls | wc -l
```

For example, in an emulator:

```
$ adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ cd sdcard
generic_x86:/sdcard $ ls | wc -l
10
```

EDIT:

For a device you can try:

```
$ adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ cd yourDirectory
generic_x86:/yourDirectory $ ls -l | grep . -c
```

Comment: *Utilities like find, **wc**, tree and tail do not seem to work*

Comment: It IS working in an emulator. I'm editing to make it work in a device.

Comment: @user96279 Did it work? If so, please accept, if not, please comment!

Comment: ls -l | grep . -c, seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue and I decide to use powershell instead of cmd.

you can get the count of the files in a directory with this:

```
$counter = $(adb shell 'ls sdcard/DCIM/Camera | wc -l') -as [int]
```

this will not apply to the folders inside, for that I thing you can get the folders using:

```
adb shell 'ls -d sdcard/DCIM/*/'
```

and then do a for loop with those routes ?

```
foreach ($folder in $(adb shell 'ls -d sdcard/DCIM/*/'))
{
     $counter = $counter + $(adb shell 'ls sdcard/DCIM/Camera | wc -l') -as [int] 
}
```

let me know how it goes,

have a great weekend!